# linux command produce Python OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, shell, networking, command

I have a problem...

```
import sys
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['traceroute -I www.yahoo.com'])
```

and I had try

```
import sys
import subprocess    
subprocess.call(['/usr/sbin/traceroute -I www.yahoo.com'])
```

why I am recieving the following error message: "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory". Can anyone help...thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to answer without knowing the much about the underlying reasons, but I've run into this before with subprocess. The call arguments list really wants a list -- I assume it is looking for an executable with spaces in the name, exactly matching what you enter. Try this instead:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['traceroute', 'www.yahoo.com'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
import subprocess
subprocess.call('traceroute -I www.yahoo.com',shell=True)
```

You can simply do this with `shell=True` option.